# Accessing Windows Security through Visual Basic

Tags: vba, windows-server, windows-security

I've created a code that copies the folder contents from PC1(pc for user) to PC2(pc for server). I used Active Directory to create accounts for the access of PC2's server

I have the ff code to transfer from PC1 to PC2:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory("C:\Users\Bounty Hounds\Desktop\1", "\\WIN-2I9JBRPFMO7\UserFiles\joshua824\Desktop\joshua824", True)

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory("\\WIN-2I9JBRPFMO7\UserFiles\joshua824\Desktop\joshua824", "C:\Users\Bounty Hounds\Desktop\1", True)
End Sub
End Class
```

This only works if you pass the server's login information that only seems to show when I try to manually enter the address of the server

[image]

I found two ways to approach this problem

First

1. Create a login form
2. Second form would tell Windows Security via vb code that my username and password are what I inputted on the login form

Second

1. Create a code that will show Windows Security automatically when running my visual basic program

However i'm struggling on how do I tell Windows Security about my login info and at the same time I don't know how do I manually show Windows Security